# Refactor this code snippet

Tags: java, refactoring

I am unable to refactor and make this snippet cleaner and smaller.
For example i want to add a new value to the listOfValues in one line, instead of first initliazing it to an empty arraylist then calling add on it on a seperate line and finally putting listofvalues in the hasmap on the third line. Also in the else statement is the hasMap.put necessary since we are getting a reference to listOfValues and if we add something to it hashMap will contain it automatically?

```
MyObject:
    key: String
    values: List<Value>

Value:
    Value1: String
    Value2: String


HashMap<String, MyObject> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

List<Value> listOfvalues;

if (!hashMap.containsKey(key)) {
    listOfvalues = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfvalues.add(Value.builder().withValue1(Value1).withValue2(Value2).build());
    hashMap.put(key, MyObject.builder().withkey(key).withvalues(listOfvalues).build());
} else {
    listOfvalues = hashMap.get(key).getvalues();
    log.info(String.format("Duplicate key: %s. Previous Value(s): %s", key,
            listOfvalues));
    listOfvalues.add(Value.builder().withValue1(Value1).withValue2(Value2).build());
    hashMap.put(key, MyObject.builder().withkey(key).withvalues(listOfvalues).build());
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow Works. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively. A demand for us to refactor your code will likely lead to getting downvotes and having the question put on hold.

Comment: That said, the builder pattern looks really clunky and unneeded here.  You really need constructors `MyValue(String v1, String v2)` and `MyObject(String key, List<Value> values)`. That would eliminate a lot of cruft.  Also if you're on Java 9 and the `listOfValue` objects are not mutated later, `List<>#of(E...)` would also help, along with factoring out the duplicated code.

Answer (score 2):

The common part with list and map working can be moved out from `if/else`:

```
Map<String, MyObject> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

List<Value> listOfvalues;
if (!hashMap.containsKey(key)) {
    listOfvalues = new ArrayList<>();
} else {
    listOfvalues = hashMap.get(key).getvalues();
    log.info(String.format("Duplicate key: %s. Previous Value(s): %s", key,  listOfvalues));
}

listOfvalues.add(Value.builder().withValue1(Value1).withValue2(Value2).build());
hashMap.put(key, MyObject.builder().withkey(key).withvalues(listOfvalues).build());
```